# 10-hour layover in Paris: Can I (Indian citizen with US visa), visit Eiffel Tower?

Tags: visas, sightseeing, paris, layovers, indian-citizens

I am traveling from India to US via Paris where I have layover of 9 hours.
My US visa is H-1B. What visa requirement do I have in order to visit Eiffel tower.
Currently I am in US.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As an Indian national with a US Visa transiting a French airport you do not generally require a visa, as you can TWOV (Transit Without Visa).  Presuming you are passing through Paris CDG airport, then this is true even if you have to change terminals as there is an air-side bus.  (At Paris ORY airport some transfers can not be made airside and will require a visa).

However TWOV will NOT allow you to enter the country, and the Eiffel tower is not even slightly visible from either airport!

Thus to visit the Eiffel Tower - or any other part of Paris - you will require a visa. As you are planning to leave the airport, you are most likely after a Schengen "Short Stay" visa, which will have to be issued by a French embassy due to the only country you're planning to visit being France.

Unfortunately this means that it'll end up being a relatively expensive visit to La Tour Eiffel.